# Display query along with results from a file

Tags: mysql

MySQL version: 5.58 MySQL Community Server

I am trying to organize the scripts we have for each of our development releases so that it is easier for our production dba to execute the scripts during the release.  I have a handful of scripts that have update, insert, delete statements and then a single master script that calls those scripts so the dba only has to call the master script during the release.

master.sql contains:
source file1.sql
source file2.sql
source file2.sql

During debugging of these scripts I am logging to a file using 'tee' and I get something like this for each query run inside of each individual sql file:

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

In this example above it wasn't able to update a row because it couldn't find a match in the where clause so I would need to look at that query to see why.  But I can't see the query because its not displayed with the results so I have to try to count the results and then look at the original file to figure out which query had the issue.  This is no big deal with a handful of queries in each file but a pain if I have hundreds of queries in a file.

My question is: Is there a way for me to have mysql display the actual query along with the results it produces without having to have some sort of print statement after each query in the file (ie.  select 'my query')?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the verbose options of the mysql client.
For instance:

```
mysql -u xxxx -pxxxx -h xxxxx -P XXXX -vvv --show-warnings --line-numbers < x.sql
```

will produce a verbose log including the text of the queries.

Comment: Each suggestion seemed worthwhile, but I think this solution will work best for my situation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `tee`, it sounds like you have a bash script.  Try echo'ing out the query (or the name of the query) before each one is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable slow query logging with 0 seconds, this way every query will be logged, this way you will get results as well as SQL statement itself. I am not sure if it provides enough information for you.

```
# Time: 121005 11:39:51
# User@Host: user[user] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.003103  Lock_time: 0.000077 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 3
SET timestamp=1349455191;
update test set end = Null;
```